# Shared example methods between rspec tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

Every model I'm testing has the same "it must have `atribute`" test, testing the `validates_presence_of` for certain attributes. So, my goal is to create a "helper" that includes this test in a modular way.

Here is what I have:

```
# /spec/helpers.rb
module TestHelpers

  # Runs generic validates_presence_of tests for models
  def validate_presence( object, attributes=[] )
    attributes.each do |attr|
      it "must have a #{attr}" do
            object.send("#{attr}=", nil)
            expect(object).not_to be_valid
          end
        end
      end

    end
```

And

```
# /spec/rails_helper.rb
# Added
require 'helpers'

# Added
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include TestHelpers
end
```

And

```
# /spec/models/business_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Business, type: :model do

  describe "Validations" do

  before :each do
    @business = FactoryGirl.build(:business)
  end

  # Presence
  validate_presence @business, %w(name primary_color secondary_color)
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
`validate_presence` is not available on an example group
```

I had read about shared_helpers and using `it_behaves_as`, but I'm not sure if that is what I'm looking for. Maybe I'm just thinking about doing this in the wrong manner.

--UPDATE--

If I place the `validate_presence` method into an `it` block, I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: it { validate_presence @business, %w(name primary_color secondary_color published) }
   `it` is not available from within an example (e.g. an `it` block) or from constructs that run in the scope of an example (e.g. `before`, `let`, etc). It is only available on an example group (e.g. a `describe` or `context` block).
```

Comment: The validation should be in an example, not in the spec's preamble.

Comment: If I put it in an `it` block, I get a different error (added to original post)

Comment: Shouldn't you be checking against `object`?

Comment: Dave, yes, but not in this minimal example. :)

Answer (score -1):

Shared examples are for testing the same logic across different models. Here you're just testing one model so it wouldn't apply to you. Even though I don't recommend testing core validators such as **presence**, here is how you would do it

```
# /spec/models/business_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Business, type: :model do
  let(:business) { FactoryGirl.build(:business) }

  context "when validating" do  
    %w(name primary_color secondary_color).each |attribute|
      it "checks the presence of #{attribute} value" do 
        business.send("#{attribute}=", nil)

        expect(business).to_not be_valid
        expect(business.errors[attribute]).to be_any
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, the `validate_presence` helper you're trying to use is part of the [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) library.

Comment: That is what I was doing across several models, which is why I was wanting to condense it down further and make more dynamic approach with a method. Aside from this, there are other tests I'm wanting to do this way, which is what led me to seeking the correct way to do it. Lastly, I'm not testing the core validator, I'm just ensuring that the validator remains in the model and doesn't get removed accidentally.